# Incorrect output when exporting AWS Redshift data to S3 using UNLOAD command

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm not a database guy and i have just started exploring Redshift. I created a cluster and used their sample scripts to populate tables. I want to copy data from Redshift to Postgres. I first wanted to export the data to S3 and then import into Postgres. After i ran the following command, a file got generated in my S3 bucket:

```
UNLOAD ('select * from date')
TO 's3://sample-dwh-data/date_' credentials
'aws_access_key_id=******;aws_secret_access_key=*************'
PARALLEL OFF;
```

This is the script i used to create `date` table in Redshift:

```
create table date(
    dateid smallint not null distkey sortkey,
    caldate date not null,
    day character(3) not null,
    week smallint not null,
    month character(5) not null,
    qtr character(5) not null,
    year smallint not null,
    holiday boolean default('N'));
```

Problem is that when i open the exported file present in S3, i see the last column for each row has values either set as `f` or `t`. Sample output from exported file:

```
2070|2008-09-01|MO|36|SEP|3|2008|t
2071|2008-09-02|TU|36|SEP|3|2008|f
```

However, if i query the Redshift table, last column value is either `true` or `false`. So, why is the `UNLOAD` command trimming the last column's value?

**UPDATE**:
@Yankee: When i ran the following command:
`'SELECT dateid,caldate,day,week,month,qtr,year,CASE WHEN holiday = true THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS holiday from date'`, i got this error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
UNLOAD ('SELECT dateid,caldate,day,week,month,qtr,year,CASE WHEN holiday = true THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS holiday from date')
TO 's3://sample-dwh-data/date_...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "TRUE" 
Position: 87;

UNLOAD ('SELECT dateid,caldate,day,week,month,qtr,year,CASE WHEN holiday = true THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS holiday from date')
                                                                                      ^                                                                                
1 statement failed.
```

Comment: why do you think this is a problem? the unload command uses t and f to represent boolean. the copy command would accept these as valid values.

Comment: The problem is that i want to load the exported data to a Postgres instance running on Heroku. I'm not sure whether this will change `f` to `false` or `t` to `true` while importing it to another database (in my case, Heroku Postgres). Also, is this common for UNLOAD operation to trim the output in case of boolean values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a `SELECT * FROM DATE`, you can specify the column names and there you can customize how you want the data to be exported, by using CASE IF ELSE conditions.

```
SELECT dateid,caldate,day,week,CASE WHEN holiday = true THEN \'TRUE\' ELSE \'FALSE\' END AS holiday from date;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. Please check the UPDATE section above.

Comment: @Technext You can try these changes:  

1. Remove the single quotes from the 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' , ie `WHEN holiday = true THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE` or  
 
2. From [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html), you should escape the single quotes with backslashes, so that'll get you:  
`WHEN holiday = true THEN \'TRUE\' ELSE \'FALSE\' END` .  

Both of these should work.

Comment: Thanks for the correction in syntax. The command did execute but result was still the same when i used your first suggestion. However, trying your second suggestion did the trick. :) Thanks. I am still interested in knowing why UNLOAD doesn't honor the actual value and instead trims it.

Comment: @Technext Great, glad it helps. I'll edit my answer, please mark it as accepted as it solves your problem. [Here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=787653), you can see that there's no documentation as to why Redshift does that.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Yankee! :)